# Is the cost of magic arrows per each or per quiverful?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, pricing

Is the cost of magic arrows for a quiver of 20 or for a single arrow?

Looking at the fountainhead arrow and trying to determine if it costs 306gp per arrow or for a quiver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s for a single arrow. Twenty arrows costs 20× the listed price.

As a hint, notice in the cost that it notes “150 gp (plus 6 gp for masterwork arrow),” as the cost to create the otherwise 306-gp item. 6 gp is the cost of a single masterwork arrow (300 gp / 50 since ammunition costs ¹⁄₅₀ what a weapon would otherwise cost).